# How to capture the Refresh event of OWA

Tags: c#, ms-wopi

In my project, I've implemented a WOPI server. Sometimes, oos prompt the message 'Sorry, your changes weren't saved. To continue editing this document, please copy your changes and refresh the page', But if I click the Refresh button, there is nothing happened.

My question is how to capture this refreshing event in my WOPI server?
[image]

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take a minute to take the [tour], especially [ask], and [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: This is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50369209/how-can-i-identify-a-refresh-event-in-office-online-365/75216262#75216262